# MySQL query with zero values

Tags: mysql, count

I have these two tables (Article and Sale):

```
id  |  name     |
====+============
1   |   milk    |
2   |   apple   |
3   |   bread   |
... |    ...    |


id  |   idArticle  |   date     |
====+==============+=============
1   |       2      | 2011-01-01 |
2   |       2      | 2011-01-01 |
3   |       3      | 2011-01-01 |
4   |       1      | 2011-01-02 |
... |      ...     |    ...     |
```

I need to get the sales for 2011/01/01: article and count

```
2011-01-01 Milk 0
2011-01-01 Apple 2
2011-01-01 Bread 1
...
```

But I don't know how to show **"Milk: 0"** because it didn't sell milk that day.

This query doesn't work:

```
SELECT s.date, a.name, COUNT(*)
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN sale s ON a.id = s.idArticle
WHERE s.date = "2011-01-01"
GROUP BY s.date, a.name
```

Comment: read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html Left join is your mistake here. Try inner join

Comment: @Bondye: but he **wants** it that way, look at the desired output (milk)...

Comment: @pOcHa `But I don't know how to show "Milk: 0" because it didn't sell milk that day.` Have you realy read this question?

Comment: @Bondye: my answer already takes care of all that, it displays the output **exactly** as desired, and is optimized for speed too (grouping before joining) - his query shows milk (as intended) but no date and displays 1 instead of 0 (and with inner join there would not be milk **at all**, do you get it now?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT "2011-01-01" AS date, a.name, IFNULL(s.total, 0)
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idArticle, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM sale
    WHERE date = "2011-01-01"
    GROUP BY idArticle
) AS s ON a.id = s.idArticle
```

Comment: just change "2011-01-01" to a @date parameter, and it will work for any day - and if you want it for a date range, then change `WHERE date = "2011-01-01"` to `WHERE date BETWEEN @dateMin AND @dateMax`, but remove date column from select...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(s.id)
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN sale s ON a.id = s.idArticle AND s.date = '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: what exactly are you counting without the `GROUP BY a.name`